# Realtime tabular output from a powershell script

Tags: powershell

The following powershell script monitors a list of servers after they are rebooted and notifies immediately once it can attach with Get-Service.

```
#start all jobs here
get-job | stop-job
get-job | remove-job

$servers =  ("localhost", "127.0.0.1", "badserver")

function Ping-Service($myservers,[int]$timeout=60, [int]$waitbetweentrys=1){
    $myservers| %{
    $computername = $_
    start-job -scriptblock {
                   param(
               [string]$computername,
               [int]$maxwait,
               [int]$waitbetween
               )
               $status = "Fail"
               $StartTime = Get-Date
               $duration = 0
                do
               {
                #if successful, break out
                try {$gs = Get-Service -ComputerName $computername -ErrorAction Stop;$status = "Success";break} catch {start-sleep $waitbetween}                               
                $duration = (New-TimeSpan $StartTime $(Get-Date)).Seconds
                } while ($duration -lt $maxwait)
               $hash = [ordered]@{"Computername" = $computername; "Type" = "Service";"Status"=$status;"Done"=$(Get-Date);"Duration"=$duration}      
               $hash
           } -ArgumentList ($computername, $timeout, $waitbetweentrys)
}
}
Ping-Service -myservers $servers -timeout 10

#loops through jobs and check for completed ones
do
   {
       #process jobs that are done
       $jobsdone = Get-Job | where State -eq 'Completed'
       $joboutput = $jobsdone | Receive-Job

       $joboutput | %{New-Object PSObject -Property $_ } |ft -AutoSize

       #remove jobs once we get the output
       $jobsdone | Remove-job

       #See if there are any jobs left     
       $jobsleft = Get-Job

       #wait 5 seconds before checking jobs
       if ($jobsleft -ne $null) {start-sleep 5}

   } while ($jobsleft -ne $null)    #continue loop while there are jobs left
```

It works well, but the output is not formated how I would like it:

```
Duration Status  Computername Done                Type   
-------- ------  ------------ ----                ----   
       0 Success localhost    5/7/2013 4:09:30 PM Service



Duration Status  Computername Done                Type   
-------- ------  ------------ ----                ----   
       0 Success 127.0.0.1    5/7/2013 4:09:31 PM Service



Duration Status Computername Done                Type   
-------- ------ ------------ ----                ----   
      10 Fail   badserver    5/7/2013 4:09:42 PM Service
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Duration Status  Computername Done                Type   
-------- ------  ------------ ----                ----   
       0 Success localhost    5/7/2013 4:09:30 PM Service
       0 Success 127.0.0.1    5/7/2013 4:09:31 PM Service
      10 Fail   badserver    5/7/2013 4:09:42 PM Service
```

However, the key is to have each result displayed in real time. Ironically, the start-job output at the top of the script is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `Format-Table` on each object in a loop, it will display them seperately. Output the orginial objects and PowerShell will do it's magic. Btw, why are you taking an object)job-output), and creating a new object that contains it? :S

Try replacing

```
$joboutput | %{New-Object PSObject -Property $_ } |ft -AutoSize
```

with

```
$joboutput
```

Or even simpler, drop `$joboutput`. Replace

```
$joboutput = $jobsdone | Receive-Job
$joboutput | %{New-Object PSObject -Property $_ } |ft -AutoSize
```

with

```
$jobsdone | Receive-Job
```

Comment: I want to add all of the outputs together as an object so I can pass this value to another script. If I modify the output as you suggest, it will output a list view with two columns.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. Is the sample incomplete(is `$jobsdone` used somewhere else)? If so, use the first part of my answer to fix the visible output only. The only thing I removed was the unnecessary object-creation and `format-table` (which BY THE WAY, destroys the object you JUST created).

Comment: just to clarify more. if you save the code as a script and run it, it would return an ARRAY of the objects, that you can store and/or pass to another cmdlet/function/script. So if the default view is a list view, run something like `myscript.ps1 | format-table -autosize`. just remember not to use a `format-...` cmdlet in the code itself as it returns a special formatobject, and not the original dataobject itself.